# contact us form submit

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, contact-form

how we know that a contact us form is submitted on a module in Joomla 1.5.

I know that after submitting contact us form **function submit()** on **components\com_contact\controller.php** is executed.

But there is any way that we  have to insert some value in database from  module if there is a contact us form is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

There are different plugins for Joomla that provide the "contact us" page. The ones that I saw, do not insert any record to the DB - they just email you the ticket using sendmail or some other utility.
If you were referring to [this code](http://www.reference.joomlademo.de/nav.html?components/com_contact/controller.php.source.html) then you can see on line 214 that an email is sent.